# Update current indentation spaces size in WebStorm 2016

Tags: javascript, ide, settings, webstorm, indentation

I need to switch from a 2 spaces indentation style to a 4 spaces one within an automatically created Ionic project.

I'm running WebStorm 2016.1 on Mac OS X.

I already tried to change:

WebStorm | Preferences | Code Style | JavaScript | Tabs and indents

and play with indent size, tab size, use tab character etc... but no change seems to have effect on existing (and new) JavaScript files.

Any idea about how to achieve it? Might some general setting prevent this changes to take effect?

Comment: 1) Try with `Code Style | Detect and use existing file indents for editing` disabled 2) Do you have `.editorconfig` in your project? Settings from there will overwrite your code style settings (and that is expected behaviour).

Comment: Yes, there's a .editorconfig file in the project dir which definitely made any settings update ineffective. Despite I should have noticed it before, I find it weird that the IDE does not warn you about that. Anyway, editing such file and reformatting the code solved my need, thank you @LazyOne

Comment: WebStorm definitely warns you about this (does for me -- the green bar on top of the file) -- maybe you have rejected it or something like that. See these examples: [1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/editorconfig.png?file=74-212772&c=true&updated=1423141067118) [2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-10%20at%2012.24.17.png?file=74-247122&c=true&rw=1344&rh=548&u=1439198865971)

Answer (score 13):

Do you have `.editorconfig` file in your project? Settings from there will overwrite your Code Style settings (and that is expected behaviour -- that's the whole nature/purpose of EditorConfig plugin).

---

**P.S.**
IDE should notify you about such behaviour (does for me). For example:

[image]

[image]